# Where should I ask the question about licensing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

So, I recently asked [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725124/which-license-for-an-open-source-project-which-may-be-but-is-not-intended-to-be) and got a closed question and a downvote without comments, even though I asked where should I then ask this question. So, I'm asking here - where should I post such a question? I'm no low rep user and have a decent understanding but was just wondering about this particular subject, and was wondering to hear the thoughts of Stack Exchange people as I have quite a high oppinion of the answers here. I looked at http://programmers.stackexchange.com but am biased to post the question there and get another downvote, so can you please suggest?

Comment: Software licensing is on topic on Programmers, but the way I read it your question seems like a legal one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legal questions are off-topic on stackoverflow, as they require, well, lawyers. If you really need legal advice, you really need a lawyer.

Further, most of your question (by word count) is even more off-topic musing about the ethics of a game-cheating app.

Answer (score 1):

there is a proposal for a Q&A site at Area51: [Open Source Licensing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58715/open-source-licensing)

Comment: thx. posted my example question.